# Conversion from boxed int to uint generate System.OverflowException

Tags: c#

I'm trying to programmatically convert a boxed int into an uint.

The code I'm using is this:

```
Type targetType = methodToInvoke.GetParameters()[index].ParameterType;
object operand = currentMethod.Body.Instructions[j - 1].Operand;
if (targetType.IsValueType)
{
    parameters[index] = Convert.ChangeType(operand, targetType);
}
```

VS tell me that targetType is of type:

```
{Name = "UInt32" FullName = "System.UInt32"}
```

Instead operand is of type:

```
object {int}
```

ChangeType throw a System.OverflowException when the value of operand is -1549600314.

- Why is this happening, provided that the two values are 32 bit long?
- How am I supposed to do this conversion?

Comment: Wait, are you asking why you can't convert a negative integer to an unsigned integer? Think about that for a second.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely what I'm asking. Maybe I'm missing the point with Convert.ChangeType but this is definitely possible. So, how am I supposed to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening, provided that the two values are 32 bit long?

Because `Convert.ChangeType` just calls methods from the `IConvertible` interface, which uses *value* semantics.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx):

> ### Convert.ChangeType Method (Object, Type)
>
> Returns an object of the specified type and whose **value** is equivalent to the specified object.

(emphasis added)

> How am I supposed to do this conversion?

It sounds like you just want a quick bitwise conversion, which can be done by just unboxing the `int` and casting to `unit`:

```
unchecked {
    parameters[index] = (uint)(int)operand;
}
```

or if you don't like unchecked operations:

```
parameters[index] = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)operand), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very clear. So I guess there isn't a "general" way to do this. I mean, in my snippet operand and targetType can be of any reasonable type, this imply that with your solution I've to manage the "int" case explicitly.

Comment: No, there's not a "generic" `BitConverter` because the process depends highly on the target and destination types.  Converting a `byte` to a `uint` is different that converting a `long` to a `short`, for example.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks.